# Python readline Auto-Complete

Tags: python, readline

I want to implement auto-complete in Command Line Interface for the following :

```
Food : 
  Fruits:
    Apples
    Oranges
  Vegetables:
    Carrot
    Beetroot
  Snacks:
    Chocolate
```

The output for the `<TAB>` would be : 
food
and so on...

Commands would be like :
`Food Fruits Apples`
or `Food Snacks Chocolate`

Came across this https://pymotw.com/2/readline/ while googling. But I don't understand how begin/end works. And how it will change for further nesting.

Any sort of help is appreciated. (Writing code in python. Prefer to use readline library)

Answer (score 0):

If you use a library like [click](http://click.pocoo.org) for making your CLI you will get this mostly for free http://click.pocoo.org/5/bashcomplete/